# Can't generate Android APK from Unity command line

Tags: c#, android, batch-file, unity-game-engine

When I run the following build script from commandline there are no errors in the build.log but also no APK is produced. Occasionally I am am able to get a build using the exact same command with no added or changed files (I have check the folder diff using Meld).

I seem to be more successful if I open and close unity but there are still no guarantees that it will build using command line. There is also added or changed files after closing unity.

It always works when running the build in unity through the GUI.

Windows command line:

```
START /WAIT "" "C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Unity.exe" -batchmode -quit -executeMethod BuildScript.BuildAndroid -logfile build.log
```

I have also tried with `-nographics` to no avail

BuildScript.cs:

```
public class EditorSetup {
  public static string AndroidSdkRoot {
    get { return EditorPrefs.GetString("AndroidSdkRoot"); }
    set { EditorPrefs.SetString("AndroidSdkRoot", value); }
  }

  public static string JdkRoot {
    get { return EditorPrefs.GetString("JdkPath"); }
    set { EditorPrefs.SetString("JdkPath", value); }
  }

  // This requires Unity 5.3 or later
  public static string AndroidNdkRoot {
    get { return EditorPrefs.GetString("AndroidNdkRoot"); }
    set { EditorPrefs.SetString("AndroidNdkRoot", value); }
  }
}

public class BuildScript {
    public static string AndroidTitle = "Android"

    [MenuItem("Custom Build/Build AndroidHeadsetClient")]
    public static void BuildAndroid()
    {
        EditorSetup.AndroidSdkRoot = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ANDROID_SDK_HOME");
        EditorSetup.JdkRoot = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("JDK_HOME");
        Debug.Log("JDK_HOME: " + EditorSetup.JdkRoot.ToString());
        Debug.Log("ANDROID_SDK_HOME: " + EditorSetup.AndroidSdkRoot.ToString());
        BuildPlayerOptions buildPlayerOptions = new BuildPlayerOptions();
        buildPlayerOptions.scenes = new[] { "Assets/Scenes/Main/" + AndroidTitle + ".unity" };
        buildPlayerOptions.locationPathName = "MyArtifact.apk";
        buildPlayerOptions.target = BuildTarget.Android;
        buildPlayerOptions.options = BuildOptions.None;
        BuildPipeline.BuildPlayer(buildPlayerOptions);
    }
}
```

File structure:

```
.
├── Assets
│   ├── Animations
│   │   ├── ...
│   ├── Animations.meta
│   ├── Animators
│   │   ├── ...
│   ├── Animators.meta
│   ├── AudioClips
│   │   ├── ...
│   ├── AudioClips.meta
│   ├── Data
│   │   ├── ...
│   ├── Data.meta
│   ├── Documents
│   │   ├── ...
│   ├── Documents.meta
│   ├── Editor
│   │   ├── BuildScript.cs
│   │   ├── BuildScript.cs.meta
│   │   ├── ...
└──...
```

Unity version: 5.6.1f1

Any help with this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You said `Build.cs` but the name of your script is `BuildScript`? What is the actual name? Can you describe what your setup is? For example, if BuildScript  is put into its own file name..How about EditorSetup? What **folder** did you put these scripts? I might be able to help but need more information.

Comment: Added a file structure above please let me know if you need more info. I have also fixed the name of the file it is actually called `BuildScript.cs`

Comment: The setup is fine. How about `EditorSetup` ? It would also be good to mention your Unity version

Comment: The `EditorSetup` class is in the `BuildScript.cs` with the `BuildScript` class. Do you want me to get specific settings from unity itself?

Unity Version has been added above.

Comment: No that's fine. I will try to replicate this with these information and determine if this is a bug or your fault. I will do that today when I have time so keep checking back.

Comment: I did try it and it works perfectly fine with 0 failure. Although I did remove the first two lines of code in the `BuildAndroid()` function because I did not want that to be modified. I suggest you comment those two lines code out too then try it. Please tell how exactly you are executing that command line. Do you open cmd first? Do you see any error?

Comment: Ok so it works when:
- Perform a fresh clone
- I open it in unity
- Close it in unity
- Open cmd and run the command
Does not work when:
- Perform a fresh clone
- Open cmd and run the command

There are no extra/Changed files that I can see after opening and closing Unity.
I see an error on the fresh clone cmd build if I leave out the editor setup commands... 
I'm not sure what the difference is between a project that has been opened in unity and one that hasn't.
I'm trying to get this working for our CI and would like not to have to open unity and close it if I can avoid it.

Answer (score 2):

[Fixed]

This could happen because of multiple issues, and the real issue here is that, Unity batchmode doesn't show proper error logs in the console or log file.

I removed the -batchmode option and ran the command. Now the command is executed with Unity Editor opened. It will now show any errors, either in the log or as a popup.

My Issue:

In my case I forgot to change some keystore parameter, and unity showed me an error popup.